# Can't click button Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can't click button with Selenium Python on this page
[link](https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2Fsprav%2Fsearch%2Fchain%2F108880815285)

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
import time
import sys

URL = "https://yandex.ru/sprav/search/chain/108880815285"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("passp-fieldlogin").send_keys("myMail@yandex.ru") # OK
# ERROR
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("What should I inputhere???").click() # ERROR

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("passp-fieldpasswd").send_keys("myPass")
```

[image]

**Image**

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of this.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button2_view_classic").click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button2_view_classic").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=submit]").click()
```

Or fast class selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button2_type_submit").click()
```

This target the button by the `type` attribute and its value `submit`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me**

```
URL = "https://yandex.ru/sprav/search/chain/108880815285"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("passp-field-login").send_keys("myMail@yandex.ru") # OK
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button2_view_classic").click() # It works
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("passp-field-passwd").send_keys("myPass")
```